# Maximo Anywhere New Look Up fields create issue

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am working on Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 - Work Execution Application. I need to show a new look up field (Created already in Maximo Asset Management) in app.xml.

After executing the app, the new field is showing in UI but its not showing respective data. Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookbook and other Anywhere documentation on the IBM site explain in detail how to do this.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.6.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/config_apps/t_add_flds_domains.html

Comment: Pl Share the IBM/Cookbook link for adding new lookup fields in Anywhere

Comment: Couldnt get values for newly added domain field from ALNDOMAIN (/oslc/os/oslcalndomain) like status - statusCode and statusDesc (Existing field)